# list_price and price_and_currency are empty but product page shows price

Tags: python, amazon-product-api

I'm trying to get price info for amazon product with ASIN: `B00BVRV8H0` using `python-amazon-simple-product-api` wrapper (https://github.com/yoavaviram/python-amazon-simple-product-api)

```
from amazon.api import AmazonAPI

AMAZON_ACCESS_KEY = 'A...Q'
AMAZON_SECRET_KEY = 'L...j'

amazon = AmazonAPI(AMAZON_ACCESS_KEY, AMAZON_SECRET_KEY, aws_associate_tag = 'test')
product = amazon.lookup(ItemId='B00BVRV8H0')

print(product.list_price)
print(product.price_and_currency)
```

Gives:

```
(None, None)
(None, None)
```

For this ASIN I get both `list_price` and `price_and_currency` equal to `(None, None)`, but when I visit product page ([https://www.amazon.com/Smoke-Pickles-Recipes-Stories-Southern-ebook/dp/B00BVRV8H0](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00BVRV8H0)) I see price.

How can I get it using this api wrapper? For other products it works fine.

Comment: What have you got so far?  Can you post minimal code?

Comment: Updated with minimal code